# How to make variables within a function accessible to the main function?

Tags: c++, function, boost, compiler-errors

I have some simple code below that I am having trouble getting to run correctly.  Essentially, I have a custom function `Create()` that creates a variant (either Point, Line, Circle) depending on the users input.  Then I call this function in the main function, and attempt to call on the variant that I created in `Create()`. This obviously doesnt work.  How can this be fixed?

```
using boost::variant; //Using declaration for readability purposes
typedef variant<Point, Line, Circle> ShapeType; //typedef for ShapeType

ShapeType Create()
{
    int shapenumber;

    cout<<"Variant Shape Creator - enter '1' for Point, '2' for Line, or '3' for Circle: ";
    cin>>shapenumber;

    if (shapenumber == 1)
    {
        ShapeType mytype = Point();
        return mytype;
    }

    else if (shapenumber == 2)
    {
        ShapeType mytype = Line();
        return mytype;
    }

    else if (shapenumber == 3)
    {
        ShapeType mytype = Circle();
        return mytype;
    }

    else
    {
        throw -1;
    }
}

int main()
{
    try
    {
        cout<<Create()<<endl;

        Line lnA;
        lnA = boost::get<Line>(mytype); //Error: identified 'mytype' is undefined
    }

    catch (int)
    {
        cout<<"Error! Does Not Compute!!!"<<endl;
    }

    catch (boost::bad_get& err)
    {
        cout<<"Error: "<<err.what()<<endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to store the return value:

```
 ShapeType retShapeType = Create() ;
 std::cout<<retShapeType<<std::endl;

 ....

 lnA = boost::get<Line>( retShapeType );
```

You can not access values that are local to a scope(in this case `if/else` statements)  outside of that scope. You can return values from functions which you are doing you just need to store that value to use it.